# Chrome Open Link In Active Tab from Bat File

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I have a Bat file which opens up a page in chrome.

I want to update this so it opens the link in the currently active tab.

Is this possible to do?

```
start chrome http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going over these command line switches - http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ - it looks like there isn't a direct way to do this.

Out of the box command line switches let you open chrome from the command line in a new window

```
chrome --new-window www.google.com
```

or in a new tab in the current window

```
chrome www.google.com
```

It may be possible to have a Powershell or VB script close the focused tab, then open a new tab, but I can see how that might not work as well.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned I looked at the switches but found nothing. I guess I just have to keep opening it in a new tab. Thanks for your help!